# Image Magick: resize and fill doesn't work

Tags: imagemagick

this is what I'm doing:

```
convert input.png -fill white -resize 2480x3508^ out.png
```

and I get:

```
convert: invalid argument for option `2480x3508^': -resize.
```

Version: ImageMagick 6.2.8 06/11/08 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org

The error doesn't present itself if the '^' at the end of the Geometry argument is removed.

Comment: As of IM v6.3.8-3 the special resize option flag '^' was added

Answer (score 3):

The Fill Area Flag (^) is available from ImageMagick v6.3.8-3 onwards. For further reference and an alternative for older versions, please check the following link.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#space_fill